# D3js: upgrading v3 to v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm starting to code in D3 javascript and I really don't know so much. I found a very nice example in Internet of a bar chart updating with dropdown and start to study and make one or two modifications. This example is in version 3 of D3 and I wanted to make it works on version 5. Could someone give me any tips on what I can do to make it work in version 5?

I will put the code below to see what changes can be made.

Best regards!

[image: Initial screen of the visualization]

[image: A selected value of the visualization]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Indicators</title>

     <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>   
     <!--  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->

        <style>
        body {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }
        select {
            display: block;
        }
        .bar {
            fill: blue;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='vis-container' align="right"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Load and munge data, then make the visualization.
            var fileName = "./indicators.csv";
            var countries = ["Austria", "Canada", "Chile", "France", "Italy",
                                   "Poland", "Spain", "Sweden", "USA"];

            d3.csv(fileName, function(error, data) {
                var indicatorsMap = {};
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    var indicator = d.indicator;
                    indicatorsMap[indicator] = [];

                    // { indicatorName: [ bar1Val, bar2Val, ... ] }
                    countries.forEach(function(field) {
                        indicatorsMap[indicator].push( +d[field] );
                    });
                });
                makeVis(indicatorsMap);
            });

            var makeVis = function(indicatorsMap) {
                // Define dimensions of vis
                var margin = { top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
                    width  = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 250 - margin.top  - margin.bottom;

                // Make x scale
                var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(countries)
                    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

                // Make y scale, the domain will be defined on bar update
                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([height, 0]);

                // Create canvas
                var canvas = d3.select("#vis-container")
                  .append("svg")
                    .attr("width",  width  + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top  + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                // Make x-axis and add to canvas
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient("bottom");

                canvas.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

                // Make y-axis and add to canvas
                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient("left");

                var yAxisHandleForUpdate = canvas.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis);

                yAxisHandleForUpdate.append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Value");

                var updateBars = function(data) {
                    // First update the y-axis domain to match data
                    yScale.domain( d3.extent(data) );
                    yAxisHandleForUpdate.call(yAxis);

                    var bars = canvas.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

                    // Add bars for new data
                    bars.enter()
                      .append("rect")
                        .attr("class", "bar")
                        .attr("x", function(d,i) { return xScale( countries[i] ); })
                        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return yScale(d); })
                        .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height - yScale(d); });

                    // Update old ones, already have x / width from before
                    bars
                        .transition().duration(250)
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return yScale(d); })
                        .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height - yScale(d); });

                    // Remove old ones
                    bars.exit().remove();
                };

                // Handler for dropdown value change
                var dropdownChange = function() {
                    var newIndicator = d3.select(this).property('value'),
                        newData   = indicatorsMap[newIndicator];

                    updateBars(newData);
                };

                // Get names of indicators, for dropdown
                var indicators = Object.keys(indicatorsMap).sort();

                var dropdown = d3.select("#vis-container")
                    .insert("select", "svg")
                    .on("change", dropdownChange);

                dropdown.selectAll("option")
                    .data(indicators)
                  .enter().append("option")
                    .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.slice(1,d.length); // capitalize 1st letter
                    });

                var initialData = indicatorsMap[ indicators[0] ];
                updateBars(initialData);
            };
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

There were a lot of changes between v3 and v5. For example, d3.scale.linear is now just d3.scaleLinear. You can review D3's release notes, but you'd honestly be better off just using another bar chart created with v5 as your template.

d3.scale.linear is now d3.scaleLinear
d3.scale.ordingal is now d3.scaleOrdinal

Axis are now built with d3.axisLeft for your y axis, and d3.axisBottom for your x axis.